# Where can I find Silverlight templates for Windows Phone 7 applications?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, ironruby

I need Silverlight in order to use IronRuby, as Silverlight provides the DRL. However, I can't find a template for creating Silverlight Windows Phone applications in Visual Studio 2012 for Windows Phone.

Can someone point me to such a template? Because all the tutorials for IronRuby on Windows Phone say to use Silverlight.

Comment: Did you properly install the Phone SDK? Which version? Can you see other (XNA) templates?

Comment: I installed Windows Phone SDK 8.0. Yes, I can see the XNA templates, just not the Silverlight templates.

Comment: Phone 8 and Phone 7 are very different beasts. Which one do you actually need?

Answer (score 2):

I just took a quick look in VS2012/Exp, all the C# Phone templates there *are* for SilverLight. They just don't say so (explicitly) any more. When you see a MainPage.xaml you're doing SL.

But do note that Project|Properties|Build also has a combobox for the target platform. If WP7 isn't in the list you'll have to install another/extra SDK.

Comment: Thanks! I ask, because I want to write an IronRuby app for Windows Phone, and all the tutorials say to start by creating a new project using the Silverlight template. Could you reference an IronRuby project for WP7 that builds in VS 2012 for Windows Phone?

Comment: No, I have never used IronRuby. Google on.

Comment: If Google were any help, I wouldn't have asked here.